# My PSU 2x2 12v connector is reversed! Why?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

The 4 pin processor core voltage connector on my PSU unit won't fit into the 4 pin socket on my motherboard! The pattern of rounded and square pins on the connector is the reverse of the pattern on the motherboard socket. Why would this be the case? Is there a purpose for the reversed pins? How can I tell if a PSU will have normal or reversed pins before I buy it? My motherboard is an Intel D865GLC Socket 478 mATX w/ Video and Sound.

Comment: What kind (make/model) of PSU is it?

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to connect the right connector? What are all the available connectors on the power supply, other than molex/sata connectors? does the motherboard connector have detachable 20+4 pins?

Comment: The PSU is a Kentek GL-KTPS-700

Comment: The motherboard has a set of 2x10 connector pins and the 2x2 pin connector; they are not detachable.

Comment: The connector on the PSU looks like this, but mirrored, so it doesn't fit the connector on the motherboard: http://0.tqn.com/d/pcsupport/1/G/6/7/-/-/atx-4pin-molex-39-01-2040.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd bet you are confusing the connectors.

Here's a picture of what your PSU is reported to have for connectors:

[image: PSU connector image]:

Your (old) motherboard has a 20-pin ATX main connector, with a 2x2 ATX auxiliary connector.

Your new PSU has a 20+4 pin ATX main connector, and a 4x2 ATX auxiliary connector (shown above as "ATX 4+4 PIN").

You should:

1. Detach the "+4" plug from the 20+4 main plug on the PSU, and don't use it.  If you can't detach it, the 20-pin part should still fit into the 20-pin ATX main connector on the board, with 4 pins hanging over the one edge, not being used.  This can happen as long as there's no components in the way (since the board was designed BEFORE 20+4 connectors existed, they may have stuck a capacitor or something in the way).
2. Use HALF the 2x4 (ATX 4+4) plug in the ATX 2x2 connector on the board. It should fit properly, with 4 pins hanging over (not being used).  It should only fit the way it's intended (they're keyed) but watch it, because you CAN jam the wrong set in if you don't pay attention and push it in hard enough.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That was exactly the problem! It works now :D May your future be blessed with infinite good fortune!!!

Comment: @kaedhen and no votes or accepted answer for the man nailing the problem down?

Comment: oops, sorry; i'm new here. Bam, there's that accepted answer good sir! However I can't vote yet as my reputation is not high enough... sigh

Answer (score -4):

Mine WAS backward...looking at the spec on both my board and the Jack in the pc it was backward, why I don't know..maybe a manufacturing mistake as the individual pins fit in any slot in its plastic housing. I had to jam it in backwards to make mine work and it did work..
So it beats me why, but all I could do was say yup that figures I would get the f'ed up version.
Seems the yellow wire is 12v hot or + and black negative...if you look at the schematic or user manual at the jacks it sometimes shows you the positive and negative conections on the mother board itself..just make sure that yellow is the + and it goes to 12v+ hot and not negative "-" and black lines to the neg or -.
Cheers.

Comment: Masked profanity is unacceptable